# Does “testfor” send a different redstone signal depending on how many entities it found?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I know if a command block testsfor things And a comparator is connected to it, it sends a  redstone signal, but does the signal change depending on how many entities/players it detects?

Answer (score 1):

*Note: I'm currently away from a device that can run bedrock edition so I can't test this. Please test before taking my word for it.*

According to [the `testfor` command docs](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/testfor):

> On success, produces a success count equal to the number of targets matching *player*, which can be measured by a [redstone comparator](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Redstone_comparator) facing away from the command block.

If it sent the same signal strength regardless of the number of entities found, it wouldn't be possible to measure.

So yes, the signal strength does vary depending on the number of entities found.